# PDO multiple fetching of same query

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I am fetching the results from a db with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC. The issue is that I am doing it twice in the same file. Is that a known issue? What would be the alternative?

Here is my code:

```
FIRST TIME

while($row = $ordersQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $totalAmount += $row['clientPrice']/100; 
        }
        echo $totalAmount;

SECOND TIME

    while($row = $ordersQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
    ....
    }
```

Whenever I remove the first fetching, the second works fine. If I have both, the second does not return anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't fetch from the DB multiple times like this. Do this instead:

```
$orders = $ordersQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

...

foreach ($orders as $val) {
    // stuff 1
}

...

foreach ($orders as $val) {
    // stuff 2
}
```

Comment: The statement handle (`$ordersQuery`) does not contain the result set. Do you mean to iterate `$orders`?

Answer (score 0):

Use fetchAll() which will return an array. You then can loop through it as many times as you want:

$orders = $ordersQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);