# While loop through PDO results stops in the middle on second call to same function

Tags: php

Please note that what I am trying to do is populate multiple drop-downs on a webpage with data from multiple different tables. I came across this problem, and debugged it down to the following, which seems to be the minimum reproducible version of the problem. I get the same results with a different class/table that has the exact same code but a different class name, and either way I'm only ever trying to do this with different instances of the same class (the commented foreach loop is included because it's something I tried and it gives the same result).

This is currently the code of my test view:

```
<?php
include 'includes/autoloader.inc.php';

$itemtype = new Itemtype();
foreach($itemtype->getTypes() as $type){
    var_dump($type);
    echo "<br>";
}
//foreach($itemtype->getTypes() as $type){
//  var_dump($type);
//  echo "<br>";
//}

$itemtype2 = new Itemtype();
echo "test1";
foreach($itemtype2->getTypes() as $type2){
    echo "enter";
    var_dump($type2);
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "done";
```

The `Itemtype()` class is this:

```
<?php
class Itemtype
{
    public $db;
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Db();
    }

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function getTypes(){
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM itemtypes";
        $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $types = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "row is ";
            var_dump($row);
            echo "<br>";

            $itemtype = new Itemtype();
            $itemtype->setId($row["id"]);
            $itemtype->setName($row["name"]);
            $types[] = $itemtype;

            echo "itemtype is ";
            var_dump($itemtype);
            echo "<br>";
        }

        return $types;
    }
}
```

So in short, the `getTypes()` method loads some objects into an array (9, to be precise), and I'm initializing this class twice and dumping the array's contents. The data contains no special characters - the 'id' column contains integers and the 'name' column is VARCHAR(25), the contents are only letters from a to z and spaces.
The output, summarized, looks like this:
-> row is [correct data]
-> itemtype is [correct data]
-> rinse and repeat 8 more times
-> full dump of the completed array, from the first time the function is called
-> [row is [correct data] / itemtype is [correct data] ] 7 times
-> row is [correct data]
-> nothing
These last 3 lines *should* read "[row is correct data / itemtype is correct data] 9 times" followed by "full dump of the completed array". But for some reason the iteration stops on the one-to-last row - I don't get the second dump from inside the `getTypes()` function, nor the last actual object, and this only after I've called the function once already with no single problem.

I've tried arranging the `getTypes()` function in several ways, most notably this one:

```
public function getTypes(){
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM itemtypes";
    $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $types = array();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "row is ";
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<br>";

        $itemtype = new Itemtype();
        $itemtype->setId($row["id"]);
        $itemtype->setName($row["name"]);
        $types[] = $itemtype;

        echo "itemtype is ";
        var_dump($itemtype);
        echo "<br>";
    }

    return $types;
}
```

In this case I get one more loop: for the second `Itemtype()` object I get 8 iterations of "[row is [correct data] / itemtype is [correct data] ]", and then "row is [correct data]" for the ninth item, and then nothing more. This means this question is not a duplicate of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024889/pdo-multiple-fetching-of-same-query).
If I uncomment the copy of the first foreach loop, I get exactly the same outcome again. It's also not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437214/resetting-array-pointer-in-pdo-results) because I execute the statement anew every time I call the method, as its answer suggests.

If necessary I can post the complete output but I don't want to clog this up too much. I am aware I am a noob and this is probably a noob question. Other questions I've found here tend to be about individual strings getting cut short. My strings are not getting cut off - the code just seems to stop iterating in the seventh or eighth loop, *but only on the second call to the function*, for no reason I can discern. The last echo in the view, saying "done", also doesn't show up.

Comment: DId you [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) or did you look in the error logs? Did you get an error message?

Comment: You didn't post the code that produces the last 4 lines of the output that you describe. Please show how you're calling the function and printing the additional output.

Comment: The `while` loop seems to be fine, since you're getting the correct output for the first 3 lines. The problem is after the function returns.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This also ensures that you correctly identified the cause of your issues and that it's not in some unrelated place.

Comment: The first block of code is how I call the function. The ```foreach($itemtype->getTypes() as $type)``` - the "getTypes()" is the call to the function. I don't have any separate code that produces the last 4 lines. The getTypes function should echo "row is" and then a var_dump of the row at the beginning, and "itemtype is" and then a var_dump of the Itemtype object. This is the code that gets interrupted. On the second call to the function, regardless of whether I instantiate a separate object, execution just *stops* between these two var_dumps.
The function does not reach the 'return'.

Comment: Ulrich, I have not identified the cause of my issues. I had code including HTML, Bootstrap and several other tables and classes. I boiled it down to this. When I take something away from this code, I don't get a problem - but obviously, I also don't get the output I want. I included the getters and setters because people gave me trouble for not including them on a previous question I asked about a different problem where they were not relevant either.

Comment: KIKO *thank you* for linking to the way to enable error reporting, I set my PDO connection to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION but I never got any exceptions or errors. I didn't know there was another way. Looks like I'm making too many connections to the database... somehow... But how to solve that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was that I was initializing the `Db` (database) class in the `Itemtype` class constructor.
This causes a `Db()` object to be included into the array for every `Itemtype` object I put in the array - and it seems even unsetting the PDO connection in the `Db` class's destructor does not close the connection to the database that that `Db()` object carries.
The solution, therefore, is to change the `Itemtype` class like so:

```
<?php
class Itemtype
{
    //public $db;
    private $id;
    private $name;

    //public function __construct(){
    //    $this->db = new Db();
    //}

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function getTypes(){
        $db = new Db(); // <--- the Db() object is no longer a class parameter but just a variable instantiated in the function
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM itemtypes";
        $stmt = $db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $types = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "row is ";
            var_dump($row);
            echo "<br>";

            $itemtype = new Itemtype();
            $itemtype->setId($row["id"]);
            $itemtype->setName($row["name"]);
            $types[] = $itemtype;

            echo "itemtype is ";
            var_dump($itemtype);
            echo "<br>";
        }

        return $types;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not sure if this is to be considered 'correct' - I did things this way initially because I had understood this was best practice. This is what's working for me, but input on this aspect is still welcome.